# How to use when condition with subquery like "NOT IN" with trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

this is my code and i don't know what wrong this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_before_insert_instruments
    BEFORE INSERT ON Instruments
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.type NOT IN (SELECT type FROM Types)) 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
      insert_new_type_or_famille();
```

But the console return me an error like "you can use subquery in the when condition...

Comment: As the error says: you can't do that in the `WHEN` condition of the trigger definition. You have to do the check in the trigger _function_ `insert_new_type_or_famille()`

Comment: Thank u ! Now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` in the body of the trigger.  That would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_before_insert_instruments
    BEFORE INSERT ON Instruments
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Types WHERE :NEW.type = t.Types) THEN
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_new_type_or_famille();
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: That's not a valid trigger in Postgres

Comment: @xToyReD . . . Perhaps the conditional logic should be incorporated into the stored procedure.

Comment: It's not a valid postgres syntax.